# Serilog MongoDB sink custom `EnrichDiagnosticContext` not saving the extra fields on error and logging all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, logging, serilog

I have set up Serilog with a MongoDB sink in my ASP.NET Core with .NET 6 web API, the logs work as there are documents in my database collection, but only the basic information is being saved on error, and the custom fields are only saved on information level logs. I want it to log only errors and include the extra fields.

**In the services**

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MongoDB(
        database: myMongoDatabase,
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error,
        collectionName: "error_logs",
        period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
            .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```

```cs
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(x =>
{
    x.IncludeQueryInRequestPath = true;
    x.GetLevel = (httpContext, elapsed, ex) => LogEventLevel.Error;
    x.Logger = Log.Logger;
    x.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
    {
        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
        if (httpContext.Request.ContentType is "x-www-form-urlencoded")
            diagnosticContext.Set("RequestForm", httpContext.Request.Form);

        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
    };
});
```

[image: The MongoDB document]